# Is it possible to reference a strings.xml file that is not saved in your res folder?

Tags: android

I am creating an app that could potentially be used in multiple educational establishments across a variety of courses with tutors who will want to be able to update some of the information within the app themselves on an ad hoc basis. I originally thought that the best way to do this would be to have the application download a new strings.xml file to the res/values folder, though I have read that you cannot update this folder/file whilst the app is packaged and running. I think a good work around for this would be to be able to save another strings.xml file elsewhere

My questions are:

1. Is this at all possible?
2. Where would I go about saving the strings.xml so that it is not
   packaged when I export the app?

note: The file will not be called string.xml so there will be no confusion etc. with the actual strings.xml.

Comment: How is this XML file going to get on the device? Is it going to be generated by the app? Uploaded onto the phone manually when you install the app? Or downloaded when the app runs?

Comment: It would be downloaded to the app when the user runs an update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "rule" of where you should put the file (minus, of couse system and other private folders you can't access). However, the logical and most common place to put a non-packaged resource that your app downloads would either be in your own applications data folder (located on the internal storage of the device) or on the external storage of the device (SD card).

To write your file to the internal storage you will need to use the context's  [openFileOutput(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. This stores the file within your apps private data directory. Use [openFileInput(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to read your stored file

To write to external storage you will need to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your manifest. After doing that, you can use FileOutputStream to write your files data when downloading. InputStream for reading (look up which input stream type would be most suitable)

Obviously, the examples I'm giving aren't fully detailed or have code but they will guide you in the right direction for storing files on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Files under the res folder are used by the compiler to autogenerate the R class that contains the ids of the strings,layouts,drawables etc...

Of course you can download a custom resource from your server and stored it in the SD as @dymmeh points. And is the most reasonable way of to achieve modification of literals but be aware, you will not be able to use the @string/string_id in your layout's xml and you will have to parse the downloaded file yourself.